# IDEA/Maven not resolving Apache POI classes

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, apache-poi

I am trying to use Apache POI with this Groovy DSL "[groovy-excel-builder](http://jameskleeh.com/groovy-excel-builder/)", while working in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3 with JDK 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 on Windows 10.

I get the following error:
`Error:(3, 1) Groovyc: unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow`

I am able to see the package and the class in IDEA by clicking on "usermodel" section of the import statements:
`import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell`

I have the following dependencies

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jameskleeh</groupId>
        <artifactId>excel-builder</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
  <version>3.16</version>
 </dependency>
```